# Directories constructed as a tree in C

Tags: c, tree, strcat

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
 /*The output file*/
FILE *fo;

/*The input file*/
FILE *fi;

/*The current character we are on*/
char c[2];
c[1]=0;

/*The array to build the word we are on*/
char *s=malloc(900000);

/* Opens the file for reading */
fi=fopen("d.txt","r");
c[0]=getc(fi);
/* While loop responsible for reading current character,
 creating the string of directories linked to that character
 , and placing the word at the end*/
while(c[0]!=EOF)
{
strcat(s,"lib\\");
/*While loop that checks the current char for a space or a newline*/
    while((c[0]!=' '&&c[0]!='\n'))
    {


       strcat(s,c);

    strcat(s,"\\");
 c[0]=getc(fi);
    }
    printf(s);
    /*Makes the directory following the string of characters (IE: Character would be c\h\a\r\a\c\t\e\r)*/
    mkdir(s);

    s=malloc(9000);
c[0]=getc(fi);

}


return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Turns out that the solution is of the sort:

```
  char *s=(char* )malloc(600);


   ...
    while(c[0]!=EOF)
    {
    strcpy(s,"lib");
    ...
    strcat(s,"\\");
        strcat(s,c);
...
mkdir(s,0777);
 printf(s);
    s=(char* )realloc(s,600);
```

However, doing this doesn't solve the problem where no directory is created through the mkdir statement.
Revised most errors, only problem would be to reduce the time it takes to complete everything, and to create the directory that it was meant to in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
char c;
...
c=getc(fi);
...
strcat(s,(char*)c);
```

This code could not work: strcat espects 2 strings, and we know that a string ends by the value 0.

You have to do

```
char c[2];
c[1] = 0;
...
c[0] = getc(fi);


   ...

   strcat(s, c);
```

And strcat doesn't realloc s, it's your responsability of having allocated the good size for s.

**EDIT:**

At the end of your loop: `s=NULL;` => C != Java.

Firstly you need to allocate s with `malloc`, eventually reallocate it with `realloc`, and free it with `free`.
strcat doesn't allocate any memory, it only copy bytes from a string to a buffer which contains a string.

Comment: `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: it's not the problem, he will get ascii characters (1 byte) correctly.

Comment: It *is* a problem, because the comparison with `EOF` might fail. See for example http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
 /*The output file*/
FILE *fo;

/*The input file*/
FILE *fi;

/*The current character we are on*/
char c[2];
c[1]=0;

/*The array to build the word we are on*/
char *s=(char* )malloc(100);

/* Opens the file for reading */
fi=fopen("d.txt","r");
c[0]=getc(fi);
/* While loop responsible for reading current character,
 creating the string of directories linked to that character
 , and placing the word at the end*/
while(c[0]!=EOF)
{
strcpy(s,"lib");

/*While loop that checks the current char for a space or a newline*/
    while((c[0]!=' '&&c[0]!='\n')){
mkdir(s,"w");
    strcat(s,"\\");
    strcat(s,c);
    c[0]=getc(fi);

    }

    /*Makes the directory following the string of characters (IE: Character would be c\h\a\r\a\c\t\e\r)*/

 printf(s);
    s=(char* )realloc(s,100);
c[0]=getc(fi);

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only thing is that this could iterate faster, as it takes a minute to complete. Elsewise, everything completes perfectly.